# Calculate quantile for each observation in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and I have the following dataframe structure:

```
data = {'name': ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"], 'value1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'value2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
data = data.transpose()
```

What I want to calculate is a new dataframe, where for each row, each column has a value corresponding to the quantile in the data.

In other words, I am trying to understand how to apply the function pd.quantile to return a dataframe with each entry being equal to the quantile value of the column in the row.

I tried the following, but I don't think it works:

```
x.quantile(q = 0.9,axis =0)
```

or:

```
x.apply(quantile,axis=0)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide your expected output? Either as code or as a table. I am not sure what you mean by "... where for each row, each column has a value corresponding to the quantile in the data."

Comment: Try `data[['value1','value2']].apply(lambda x:x.quantile(q = 0.9,axis=0)`

Comment: Is there really no way to do this in python? Am interested in this myself. What I think the user is asking is: say you have a numeric variable and you want to split into septiles. Then all the cases that belong to say the first of the septiles are designated as 1, the second as 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you transpose your data and as per pandas documentation here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

> When the DataFrame has mixed dtypes, we get a transposed DataFrame
> with the object dtype

Your dataframe after loading looks like below, which means it has 'mixed dtypes' (one column is object / category and the other two are integers).

```
  name  value1  value2
0    a       1       1
1    b       2       2
2    c       3       3
3    d       4       4
4    e       5       5
5    f       6       6
6    g       7       7
7    h       8       8
```

In this case you transpose your data and it is being converted to object dtype, which means that `quantile` function does not understand it as numbers.

Try removing transposing step and use axis argument to decide for which direction you want to calculate quantiles.

By the way, you can do transposition with:

```py
df = df.T
```